# Some html+css code make all page shift

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, shift

I have notice that shift on 2 html+css pages are different. When i start to look at code, i find that this piece of code shift page on 5-10px to the right, and i cant understand why it happens. Maybe you will notice why.

```
    <div class='logo-text'>
        <hr>
        <div id='logo-text-h'>Events</div>
        <div id='logo-text-l'>Short text about upcoming events</div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.logo-text
{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 70px auto 40px auto;
}
#logo-text-h
{
    width: 150px;
    margin: -40px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 350%;
    background-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, 1);
}
#logo-text-l
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
}
.logo-text hr
{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Site on hosting here:

1. http://koryato.yomu.ru/index.html -shifted to the right.
2. http://koryato.yomu.ru/about.html

Comment: I can't see what you're talking about; it looks centered to me. Can you post a marked-up screenshot, a comparison of a good vs. a bad render, something along those lines?

Comment: Which two pages? Can you paste both the URLs here?

Comment: Screenshots

 1. http://yadi.sk/d/NJfD69PNMTSAa
 2. http://yadi.sk/d/PGmJsUSuMTSKM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the vertical scroll bar on the right of the screen. Some of your pages are tall enough to display a vertical scroll bar, and some aren't. One way to fix that is to use:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

which forces a vertical scroll bar to appear on every page.

Comment: Page shifted by x coordinate, not y.

Comment: Right, because the vertical scrollbar is taking up some of the page's width. I believe that overflow-y should fix your problem, but you can also try overflow-x if you think that'll work instead.

Comment: The idea being is that you want to force the scrollbar to show all the time and, by doing so, always take up the space (by the scrollbar) making the page to have a fixed width and avoiding the need to shift in the x coord

Comment: Oh... You were rights. Sorry for havent noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your website width might is bigger than the browser. Instead of using `margin: -8px` on you `.container` and `.footer` just set:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

or

```
* {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats havent solve problem, but anyway thanks about that advice.